# Tablesorter sort table using relative dates column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

How do I use tablesorter so as to sort a table based on column that has relative dates.
E.g.:
I have something like:

2 days ago 
5 days ago 
10 days ago 
1 weeks ago 
3 weeks ago

And current sorting gives:

10 days ago 
1 week ago 
2 days ago 
3 weeks ago 
5 days ago

Desired Output:

2 days ago 
5 days ago
10 days ago 
1 week ago 
3 weeks ago

PS: I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the data libraries, like [sugar](http://sugarjs.com/dates) or [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

[This demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-dates.html) uses the [sugar](http://sugarjs.com/dates) library to sort a column with that format.

[Get the parsers from here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-date.js)

```
/*! Sugar (https://sugarjs.com/docs/#/DateParsing)
* demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/7z0ss5xn/
*/
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "sugar",
    is: function() {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        // Add support for sugar v2.0+
        var create = Date.create || Sugar.Date.create,
            date = create ? create(s) : s ? new Date(s) : s;
        return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : s;
    },
    type: "numeric"
});

/*! Datejs (http://www.datejs.com/)
* demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/zge0L2u6/
*/
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "datejs",
    is: function() {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        var date = Date.parse ? Date.parse(s) : s ? new Date(s) : s;
        return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : s;
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```